# Assigning generics function to delegate in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript, delegates

I can't get this simple code snippet to compile in Typescript (1.8)

```
function test<T>(a: string, input: T): T {
    return input
} 

const xyz: (a: string, b: number) => number = test<number>
```

I have a function that takes a delegate, but converting the generics function into that delegate format requires me to perform this extra step:

```
const xyz: (a: string, b: number) => number = (a,b) => test<number>(a,b)
```

... which does not seem ideal to me.  Any ideas why this does not work, or if there is another syntax to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the generic constraint at all, this will do:

```
const xyz: (a: string, b: number) => number = test;
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20test%3CT%3E(a%3A%20string%2C%20input%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20input%0A%7D%20%0A%0Aconst%20xyz%3A%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number%20%3D%20test%3B))

The compiler infers the generic constraint to be number based on the type you explicitly defined for the variable.
Another way to do it is:

```
const xyz = test as (a: string, b: number) => number;
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20test%3CT%3E(a%3A%20string%2C%20input%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20input%0A%7D%20%0A%0Aconst%20xyz%20%3D%20test%20as%20(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number%3B))

Comment: You are right! I still find it somewhat awkward that you can't use the type constraint in this case.

Comment: Well, the compiler doesn't like the syntax `let a = test<number>`, you are supposed to use the generics constraints only when invoking the function.