# TypeScript Generic Function - "Argument not assignable error" when applying function for array

Tags: typescript, generics

#### Description

I would like like to define a Generic function in TypeScript so that it would apply a transformation to the array argument and then return an array of same type. (TypeScript version used: v3.24)

Simplified code snippet as follow:

```
describe("generic functions", function () {
    it("should not give transpilation error", function () {
        // given
        function myFunction<T>(arr: T[]): T[] {
            // ...... apply some transformation to the array here
            return arr; // or return a copy of the array of same type
        }

        let arrays = [
            ["a"],
            [1]
        ]; // Just for demonstration purpose, the actual input has more varieties of types

        // These can be transpiled without error
        myFunction(["b"]);
        myFunction([2]);
        arrays.map(myFunction);

        // This gives transpilation error, see following for the detailed message
        arrays.map(arr => myFunction(arr));
    });
});
```

In particular I am not sure why the TS compiler would fail to recognize the type only when I am applying the function to an array of mixed type and calling it explicitly.

The transpilation error message is:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string[]| number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
>     Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
>       Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

#### Similar question

1. [Assigning generics function to delegate in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548715/assigning-generics-function-to-delegate-in-typescript) - But I would like to keep the generic signature as I want my function to be more flexible
2. [Typescript Generic type not assignable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921854/typescript-generic-type-not-assignable-error) - But my function is returning the generic type.

(Apologies and please let me know if this duplicates with another question - I had tried to search but failed to find question that could answer this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is having trouble unwrapping the `(string[] | number[])` type to infer the type argument. In this case, explicitly passing the type argument will work:

```
arrays.map(arr => myFunction<string | number>(arr));
```

This is one of those cases where the compiler treats:

```
(string | number)[][]
```

Differently to:

```
(string[] | number[])[]
```

If you use the latter, it infers the type argument as `string[]`, which then fails for `number[]`.

You can help the compiler with a type guard, but this example is really thought exercise and I can't imagine wanting to use this in real life:

```
function isStringArray(arr: any[]): arr is string[] {
    return (typeof arr[0] === 'string');
}

arrays.map(arr => (isStringArray(arr)) ? myFunction(arr) : myFunction(arr));
```

Even though it calls `myFunction` either way, it can infer the type argument as `string[]` and `number[]` in each case.